# How to remove/hide body parameter from Swagger UI from file upload API

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm newbie to swagger UI development using jersey framework. I'm looking out to resolve the below mentioned issue.

**Issue**: Unable to remove/hide body parameter from Swagger UI. Please refer the attached swagger-ui screen for details.

[image]

Please find my Java source code:

```
@POST @Path("/createSchedule") 
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }) 
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST, value = "Create a new export schedule(s)") @ApiImplicitParams({ @ApiImplicitParam(name = "file", value = "Upload the template (.xlsx) to create schedule(s).", required = true, dataType = "file", paramType = "formData") }) 
public Response createSchedule(@FormDataParam(value="file") InputStream inputStream, @FormDataParam(value="file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws ScheduleException {
********* Code to process the uploaded file. **********
}
```

I have used Jersey 2.29.1(jersey-container-servlet) & Swagger 1.5.0 (swagger-jaxrs) API's. Also do let me know how to allow only specific file extensions (like .xlsx) to upload from swagger ui.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by doing below changes in the code:

1. Have changed the swagger maven dependency from "**swagger-jaxrs**" to "**swagger-jersey2-jaxrs**"
2. Include "@ApiParam" swagger annotation with resource method parameter as "**@ApiParam(hidden = true)** @FormDataParam(value = "file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData".

Refer the issue fixed swagger ui screen:
[image]